# Dagger/MissingBinding okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, mvvm, dependency-injection, singleton, dagger-hilt

I am new with dagger-hilt. I can't solve this issue.

This is the error I'm facing :

```
\com\example\news\NewsApplication_HiltComponents.java:129: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
  public abstract static class SingletonC implements NewsApplication_GeneratedInjector,
                         ^
      okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor is injected at
          com.example.news.di.NetworkModule.provideOkHttpClient(interceptor)
      okhttp3.OkHttpClient is injected at
          com.example.news.di.NetworkModule.providesNewsService(�, okHttpClient)
      com.example.news.api.NewsService is injected at
          com.example.news.data.repository.NewsRepository(newsService)
      com.example.news.data.repository.NewsRepository is injected at
          com.example.news.presentation.viewmodel.NewsViewModel(newsRepository)
      com.example.news.presentation.viewmodel.NewsViewModel is injected at
          com.example.news.presentation.viewmodel.NewsViewModel_HiltModules.BindsModule.binds(arg0)
      @dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelMap java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>> is requested at
          dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.ViewModelFactoriesEntryPoint.getHiltViewModelMap() [com.example.news.NewsApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC ? com.example.news.NewsApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC ? com.example.news.NewsApplication_HiltComponents.ViewModelC]
```

This is the Network module class:

```
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
@Module
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesRetrofit(): Retrofit.Builder {
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providesNewsService(retrofitBuilder: Retrofit.Builder, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): NewsService {
        return retrofitBuilder.client(okHttpClient).build().create(NewsService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Need some help on this error. I don't understand why this error is coming.

Comment: Issue resolved. I was not using interceptor value in  provideOkHttpClient().

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved:
I was not using interceptor in addInterceptor()

```
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(interceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor) : OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()**.addInterceptor(interceptor).**build()
    }
```